# What is the surface integral of the sureface

Tags: multivariable-calculus

What is the surface integral of the sureface $S$ where $S$ is on the cylindrical surface $x^2+z^2=2az$ that cut by another surface $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. I couldn't even draw this thing out

Answer (score 1):

Well you have just an intersection of a cylinder and a cone. Use standard formula $\underset{D}{\int \int }\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}\right)^2}\text{dx dy}$.
Here $f(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ so $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}$ wil be $\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ and $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}$ wil be $\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$. And then just use a little effort.:)

In your case you have the cone in the ${(x,z)}$ plane, defined as $(z - a)^2+x^2=a^2$ or $f(x,z)$ so it would be easier to use a slightly different expression: $\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\partial f(x,z)}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial f(x,z)}{\partial z}\right)^2}$
$\begin{gathered}D_{xz}= \left\{(x,z) \in\mathbb{R}^2\colon\,(z - a)^2+x^2\leqslant a\right\}\\ 
f'_x= \frac{-x}{\sqrt {z^2-x^2}}~~\Rightarrow~~{f'_x}^2 = \frac{x^2}{z^2-x^2},\quad f'_z= \frac{z}{\sqrt {z^2-x^2}}~~ \Rightarrow~~ {f'_z}^2 = \frac{z^2}{z^2-x^2}  \\ds= \sqrt{1 + {f'_x}^2 + {f'_z}^2}\,dxdz = \sqrt{1 + \frac{x^2}{z^2-x^2}+\frac{z^2}{z^2-x^2}}\,dxdz = \sqrt{\frac{2z^2}{z^2-x^2}}\,dxdz \\
 S=\iint\limits_{D_{xz}}ds= \iint\limits_{D_{xz}}\sqrt{\frac{2z^2}{z^2-x^2}}dxdz, \mbox{where } D_{xz} \mbox{ is the area of your cone}. \end{gathered}$

Comment: Sorry, it is not a spehere, it should be a cone isn't it?

Comment: @jason oh, well, surely it's a cone. My fault.